# $\Sigma \ \vdash A \lor B \ \ $

Tags: logic

I'm stuck with the following question:

> > prove or disprove the following:
> >
> > if $\Sigma \ \vdash A \lor B  \ \ $ then $\ \ \Sigma \ \vdash A \ \ $  or $\ \ \Sigma \ \vdash B $

Thanks.

Comment: What axiom system are you using?

Comment: Note that this would imply that for all $P$, $\Sigma \vdash P$ or $\Sigma \vdash \lnot P$, because surely $\Sigma \vdash P \lor \lnot P$...

Comment: Unless, of course, you're working in something like intuitionistic logic, where you *don't* have $\Sigma \vdash P \lor \lnot P$ for arbitrary $P$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may refute the "purported rule" with this counterexample.

Let $\Sigma = \{ A \lor B \}$;

clearly : $A \lor B \vdash A \lor B$.

In *classical* propositional logic, we have that $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ iff $\Sigma \vDash_{TAUT} \varphi$.

Thus, if the "purported rule" woul be sound, we would have :

> $A \lor B \vDash_{TAUT} A$ or $A \lor B \vDash_{TAUT} B$.

Now, we use another property of the *tautological consequence* relation :

> $\sigma \vDash_{TAUT} \varphi$ iff $\vDash_{TAUT} \sigma \rightarrow \varphi$.

Thus, form the above we may conclude :

> $\vDash_{TAUT} (A \lor B) \rightarrow A$ or $\vDash_{TAUT} (A \lor B) \rightarrow B$.

But neither $(A \lor B) \rightarrow A$, nor $(A \lor B) \rightarrow B$ are *tautologies*.