# If $\Sigma\vdash A \lor B$ then $\Sigma \vdash A$ or $\Sigma \vdash B$

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I'm a new student for Mathematical Logic and I am trying to solve this question:

In Hilbert proof system, prove or disprove the following: if $\Sigma\vdash A \lor B$ then $\Sigma \vdash A$ or $\Sigma \vdash B$.

I know that this is the same question in [$\Sigma \ \vdash A \lor B \ \ $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/732838/sigma-vdash-a-lor-b) but the answer contains things I haven't learnt. So please don't remark as duplicate.

I'm only at the beginning of system proofs and only know that if  $\vdash A$ $\iff$ $A$ is tautology, I don't know if it's even relevant.

I am stuck as $\Sigma$ may be any set of propositions, but I think I need to disprove.

Comment: Maybe think about the case where $B = \lnot A$?

Comment: If I assume the proposition is true, then I get that $\Sigma \vdash A$ or $\Sigma \vdash \neg A$. I don't see how this could help me... Can you please elaborate? @MJD

Comment: Suppose $A$ is undecidable under $\Sigma$.

Comment: I still can't see how does this somehow lead to contradiction. @RobertShore

Comment: The point is that $\Sigma$ *always* proves $A \lor \lnot A$ because the latter statement is a tautology, but it may be the case that neither $\Sigma \vdash A$ or $\Sigma \vdash \lnot A$ is true.

Comment: and how can I show this? that there is some A that neither $\Sigma \vdash A$ or $\Sigma \vdash \neg A$ is true? @RobertShore

Comment: How can you show that *ever* happens?  One example will suffice.  Do the axioms of a field of characteristic $0$ prove or refute the statement:  $\exists x~(x^2+1=0)$?

Comment: You need to provide more context: there are many different Hilbert proof systems.  Which one are you using?